# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.riediger.teams.logic.to.TeamTO

Tags: java, jsf, classcastexception

I have a strange problem right now (see title of question). It says it cant cast to said object even though there should be no casting required.

JSF-Page: http://pastebin.com/0aFNWc4h
Bean: http://pastebin.com/vtA552fA

Every selected item of the SelectManyCheckbox should be stored as TeamTO-object in this list.

Field declaration in the Bean:

```
private List<TeamTO> preSelectionRecipientsTeams;
```

Snippet from the jsf page:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="preSelectionRecipientsTeams" value="#{sendMailBean.preSelectionRecipientsTeams}">
```

Upon trying to iterate over this list

```
for (TeamTO t : getPreSelectionRecipientsTeams()) {...}
```

I get said error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to debug to see which object are in the list in fact? there is a case it fills with Strings in some other place in the code.

Comment: post code **here**...  not somewhere else... and make it an [mcve]

Comment: "System.out.println(getPreSelectionRecipientsTeams());" prints "Information:   [TeamTO#2, TeamTO#10]" (correct behavior after selecting some objects via the SelectManyCheckbox)

Comment: @Kukeltje Why have you removed the jsf tag? It seems to be applicable to me.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check the code (I never look at external files) and there is a jsf page... so it could indeed be jsf related. Sorry, I'll re-add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getPreSelectionRecipientsTeams()
```

contains Strings, although it shouldn't, judging from it's type.

Find the place where it get's it content from and fix that.

From your updated question I infer the following:

Your bean contains a collection of the desired type, but you have not registered a converter to make JSF actually convert the Strings, it receives via http into those objects.

So: write a Converter and register it to your JSF component.

Probably a good point to start reading about all this is: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/jsf_apps/eventvalidate/sf_avc_process.html

Comment: preSelectionRecipientsTeams is a List of Strings.


         `private List<TeamTO> preSelectionRecipientsTeams;`


The selected items of the SelectManyCheckbox should be stored as TeamTO in said list.


         `<h:selectManyCheckbox id="preSelectionRecipientsTeams" value="#{sendMailBean.preSelectionRecipientsTeams}">`


Am I overseeing some jsf-specific conversion of types?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not even trying to decipher code in comments. If you think it is relevant to the question, put it in the question.